Changing Gear Feels Off After TRS
So i have a 2008 Accord EX V6 with 156k miles, recently i had a check engine light with the D flashing too, i scanned it and it was my transmission range switch or neutral safety switch.
I bought an aftermarket part Standard Motor Product NS-577 from Amazon and I had it installed today. When I change gears from top to down: P to R to N it has the old feel, a bit hard but seems normal, but when I shift to D, D3, 2 and 1 it’s super smooth I can barely feel the gear changing. However when I shift from bottom to up from 1,2,D3, D, N, R, P it is somewhat smooth as hell.
i am curious if it takes some time for the transmission to learn or adjust to this new range switch or if the mechanic didn’t align it properly or I just got a trash part.

Additionally what might be a good way to tell if their installation was improper? They deleted the CEL code on it, but I also had D flashing from way before that was related to this issue, if the switch was not properly installed I can reasonably assume that the D will flash once again later on, right?
